# Custom google maps not working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I want to use a custom google maps on my website but I'm not able to do it.

I'm trying to copy this custom google [map](https://codyhouse.co/gem/custom-google-map/):

But on my website I can't see the address nor the +- buttons. I downloaded the files and copies the html, css and js on my code but it's not working.

Link to my [website](http://clients.sabrinacouto.com/brisk/):  The map is at the bottom.

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add your screenshot in question?

Comment: I can't because I haven't enough reputation to post more than 2 links or images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set display none to the sidebar-wrapper element you can see them.

Your map width is 100% and the symbols + and - are behind your sidebar.

Just try to adjust he positioning of this elements (or reducing the size of the map, for example) and it will work.

Comment: I tried it but it's the same, you can check it on my link. Now the map has a 50% width and it's on the right but I can't see the address and the +- with the colours. If I add display none to the sidebar-wrapper the menu disappear.

Comment: The display:none on the sidebar was just for finding the buttons, don´t add it to your stylefiles. 
You should add this code to your styling files:
#cd-zoom-in{background-color: rgba(211, 104, 104, 0.9);} to set a background to + and - symbols and make them more visible.
And #google-container{width:100%;margin-left:0;} to respositioning the map.

Comment: ah yes, now it works. Do you know how to change the colour of the location icon?  and how to colocate the address on top of the map like in the example? Thanks!